# Solving for 4 variables-algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, substitution

I encountered a problem with 4 variables and I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this:
This is what is known:

$$ \left\lbrace
\begin{align}
a+b &= 1800 \\
c+d &= 12 \\
a/c &= 100 \\
b/d &= 250 \\
(a+b)/(c+d) &= 150
\end{align}
\right.$$

Below is a screenshot from a spreadsheet. The red numbers are the 4 unknowns that I'm trying to figure out how to solve for (I happen to know them, but would love to understand how to solve for them when I do not know them).
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlb4A.png)
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a/c = 100 \implies a = 100c \\ b/d = 250 \implies b = 250d$$

Substitute this into $a+b = 1800$ to get $100c+250d = 1800$.  Divide by $50$ to get $2c+5d = 36$.  From $c+d = 12$, we have $c = 12-d$, so $2(12-d)+5d = 36$.

$3d = 12 \iff d=4$, so $c = 12-4=8$.  Hence $(a,b,c,d) = (800,1000,8,4)$

Answer (score 2):

Linear algebra will do ... we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+b=1800 \\
c+d=12
\end{eqnarray*}
and $a=100c$, $b=250d$ sub these into the first equation & cancel a factor of $50$. (Note that the fifth equation is satisfied by virtue of the first two.)
\begin{eqnarray*}
2c+5d=36 \\
c+d=12
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be a doddle from here ?

Answer (score 0):

$b=1800-a$

$d=12-c$

$\cfrac ac=100$

$a=100c$

$\cfrac {1800-a}{12-c}=250$

$\cfrac {2.5a}c=250$

$\cfrac {1800-a}{12-c}=\cfrac {2.5a}c$

$\cfrac {1800-100c}{12-c}=\cfrac {2.5(100c)}c$

$1800c-10c^2=250c(12-c)$

Which gives you the value of $c$